# Orlan suit inside arm/hand access

Tags: eva, spacesuits

I have heard than under some conditions a user of the Orlan EVA Suit can retract his/her arm inside the suit torso, then re-insert arm into suit sleeve and glove (under suit pressure). Can you confirm this? And where can I get more info on this, with specific instances?

Answer (score 7):

[Gerhard Thiele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Thiele) confirmed in an old [ESA blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20110825114726/http://quiz.esa.int/page.php?id=11276) that the Orlan suit had enough room to lean to one side and pull your arm out of the glove and sleeve to scratch an itch. I couldn't find any further information on this though.