# What do astronauts do if they feel like itching during space-walk?

Tags: iss, eva

Astronauts need to regularly go out of ISS for the purpose of maintenance and repair. What happens if they start feeling itching inside the spacesuit? Do they have to go back inside? Do they use any medicine for not having itching? Or is it that in space it doesn't itch at all?

Comment: Related: [How do astronauts on EVA deal with nose itching?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12922/how-do-astronauts-on-eva-deal-with-nose-itching)